# Corporate alternatives to DropBox for iPad

Tags: ipad, windows, ms-office, dropbox

I am currently the only iPad user in a large company, and am loving using it, especially for meetings. I keep a lot of information relevant to meetings on DropBox, such as minutes, reports, spreadsheets and so on, and tend to refer to them a lot. I like the fact that I can easily navigate my own directory tree in DropBox, and view common file formats on there. However, whilst I have permission to use dropbox for the files I use, I find that I am limited in scope with some meetings, as I'm not allowed to place others on servers that don't belong to the company. I end up having to either bring a laptop, or, more commonly, look over somebody else's shoulder.

So, can anyone recommend a solution similar to Dropbox that would work for shares on Windows Server 2003, and allow me to:

- Easily navigate a directory tree, possibly with shortcuts to commonly-used folders
- View files in MS Office 2003 and 2007 formats and PDFs without lengthy conversion processes
- Not have to go through an intermediate "copy to the iPad" step that I might find with, say GoodReader or Quickoffice

I'd ideally lie a solution that works on the company wifi network without further modification of the current server architecture, though I can see that in the future, it may need to work over a secure VPN connection from the field if a few other managers decide to take the plunge, so something that's preferably easy for our system administrators to configure and support. A proxy solution that would work in Linux or Windows is possible.

Comment: Just to re-phrase, you mean that by company policy you're forbidden to add files to dropbox which is the limiting factor on its usage for you, right?

Answer (score 4):

A search on the iTunes store for SMB file browsers finds something called - ahem - FileBrowser that sounds like what you need. Haven't tried it myself - although thinking about it something like this might be a help in my workflow. Did I just cost myself $3 by answering a question?

It's at http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/filebrowser-access-files-on/id364738545?mt=8

Comment: +1 for FileBrowser. I have used it quite a bit to get at SMB shares on both my MacBook Pro and Windows PCs.

Comment: +1 Too. Using it currently on a mixed Linux, Windows, Mac network and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

I've looked for similar things in the past.  I think the best short answer is: "There is nothing remotely similar to dropbox on the iPad that works on Windows shares."

You might want to investigate the encryption that dropbox uses.  I think all the files on their server are encrypted using a key which is only stored on your ipad?  You might be able to convince your management/IT people that it's okay for you to use dropbox for documents that need to be secure.

Update:
I've been using a program called BoxCryptor which sits on top of DropBox and adds another layer of encryption.  It runs on my Mac and on my iPad.  I don't know if it's available for Windows, I don't see why not.  I've been using it for a few weeks for some small spreadsheets and it works fine so far.

Comment: Amen to that. @moof You could also try convincing your management/IT to encrypt sensible files on your end regardless of what server is being used. After all, that's more secure than trying to enforce some policy on people *not* bringing files outside the company. I'm pretty sure every file you are worried about is already out of companies servers one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Box.net may be a suitable replacement. I know other iPad owners who have used it for some of these tasks.

Comment: This is the quintessential 2012 era corporate version of DropBox - larger storage quotas, more business and sharepoint oriented services and many small and large businesses use both DropBox and Box.net efficiently and the other way in some cases.

Comment: The iOS apps are not currently compatible with a localized, site specific Box, ie yourcompany.box.com.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if this will apply on your case, but give [Tonido](http://tonido.com) a shot. I know [I am](https://superuser.com/questions/175243/backup-sync-and-search-files-over-internet-and-intranet) (still going to) try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a WebDAV->SMB gateway and use Pages or other WebDAV capable clients to access it...

http://davenport.sourceforge.net/